# Woocommerce with wordpress 2023 child theme : taxonomy-product-cat.php file not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created taxonomy-product-cat.php in `wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/templates/taxonomy-product-cat.php` and made customizations but the clild theme only loading data from parent theme only.
same is working fine with 2021 child theme.

followed official docs https://woo.com/document/template-structure/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The file must be placed in the WooCommerce folder without the "templates".

```
/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/taxonomy-product-cat.php
```